# date format convertion creates NaT in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, validation

i have a df column startdate i want to convert it to yyyy-mm-dd format i used

```
df1['startdatecheck'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['startdate'], format= '%m/%d/%Y', errors='coerce')
```

but the output i get is

df1

| startdate | startdatecheck |
| --- | --- |
| 01/31/2021 | 2021-01-31 |
| 01/31/2021 | 2021-01-31 |
| 02/29/2021 | NaT |
| 01/31/2021 | 2021-01-31 |
| 02/29/2021 | NaT |

02/31/2021 date is converted as NaT , thanks in advance
the desired output is

| startdate | startdatecheck |
| --- | --- |
| 01/31/2021 | 2021-01-31 |
| 01/31/2021 | 2021-01-31 |
| 02/29/2021 | 2021-02-29 |
| 01/31/2021 | 2021-01-31 |
| 02/29/2021 | 2021-02-29 |

Comment: There is no `02-31`... February only has 29 days at most.

Comment: changed the date but still getting NaT

Comment: Feb 2021 has only 28 days

Comment: got it my mistake changed the date now its working